# Reading line by line and tokenizing input?

Tags: java, string

I have a String which has the following:

```
Aaa     Blll Chhh    D
Rrr   q h j 9 5
h 8 i
```

The lines are because there are '\n' characters in the string.

I need to be able to put this into a 2D array of String.

What separates things is white space.

So the output of this is:

```
["Aaa"]["Blll"]["Chhh"]["D"]
["Rrr"]["q"]["h"]["j"]["9"]["5"]
["h"]["8"]["i"]
```

Example:

```
strings[1][0] is "Rrr"
strings[2][2] = "i"
```

What could I use to tokenize my input string?

Thanks

Comment: But lines number is not fixed, you can't use array[][].

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan, `T[][]` is [jagged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) in Java.

Comment: Yes can has dynamic rows length (2-nd dimension), but first dimension is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] lines = input.split("\n\r?|\r");
int nLines = lines.length;
String[][] fields = new String[nLines][];
for (int i = 0; i < nLines; ++i) {
  fields[i] = lines[i].trim().split("[ \t]+");
}
```

If the input string can have an empty row or zero rows, then you might need to handle all-whitespace lines or all-whitespace inputs as a special case because `"".split(...)` is `new String[] { "" }`, not `new String[0]`.

Comment: Do you mean fields[i] = lines[i]...?